# Gitlab-ci problems pushing to the private registry with HTTPS

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to push an image to my registry with the gitlab ci. I can login without any problems (the before script). However I get the following error on the push command. `error parsing HTTP 400 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<html>\r\n<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\r\n<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"`

This in the config.toml from the used gitlab-runner

```
[[runners]]
  name = "e736f9d48a40"
  url = "https://gitlab.domain.com/"
  token = "token"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

This is the relevant part of the gitlab-ci

```
image: docker
    
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  BACKEND_PROJECT: "test"
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

 containerize:
  stage: containerize
  before_script:
    - "docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY"
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - "cd backend/"
    - "docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/api:latest ."
    - "docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/api:latest"
```

The GitLab omnibus registry configuration

```
registry_external_url 'https://gitlab.domain.com:5050'

registry_nginx['enable'] = true
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.domain.com/privkey.pem"
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.domain.com/fullchain.pem"

registry_nginx['port'] = 443
registry_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true

### Settings used by Registry application
 registry['enable'] = true

 
registry_nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
"Host" => "$http_host",
"X-Real-IP" => "$remote_addr",
"X-Forwarded-For" => "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for",
"X-Forwarded-Proto" => "http",
"X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
}
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the solution was quite simple. I only had to change the

```
"X-Forwarded-Proto" => "http",
```

to

```
 "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
```